# Impersonation error connecting from Outlook 2016 x64

Tags: iis-7, outlook-addin, impersonation

When connecting to an IIS 7 website from an Outlook Addon, appear this error:

> **An anonymous identity cannot perform an impersonation.**

The impersonation is invoked inside the website:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
impersonationContext =((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate();
```

Oddly, it is working from Outlook 2010-2013 x32, but not from Outlook 2016 x64.

Same code is working in another IIS server (with the difference that Exchange is installed on the server). WebServer roles and IIS config seems to be the same in both servers (Windows Server 2008).

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like the website on this IIS 7 machine uses anonymous authentication.

Comment: But I've tried with anonymous authentication enabled and disabled